# Install brew without prompt password

Tags: bash, homebrew

I want to create a script to automate the installation of brew on new workstations without entering password. In my `/etc/sudoers` I added the path to my file

```
dsi ALL = (ALL) ALL
dsi ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /Users/dsi/Desktop/Hello/script.sh
```

But I still have to write the password if I execute the script with a simple `./script.sh`. If I execute the script with `sudo ./script.sh` I get the error `Don't run this as root!`

script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

yes '' | /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
brew cask install vlc
```

I find [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/366924/312451) solution but I don't like because I must write the password in clear

Comment: what's the back story here? Normally I install brew once - the only root / enhanced permissions needed is to set up the permissions and directory so that a root / sudo is never needed again. I wonder if there's a better, larger problem to solve...

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to type the password every time I install homebrew on new computers

Comment: Normally brew doesn't require to run as sudo - why do you need it ??

Comment: If I run `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"` the terminal ask me for password

Comment: Are you running the installation as an admin user? Also, if you need to modify the sudoers file on each machine I don't see the benefit somehow.

Comment: Yes I run it as admin user. I login in the session with the admin account and with this account I run the command

Comment: `I find this solution but I don't like because I must write the password in clear` - humm if you refer to the script I had created in the thread you have linked to, then NO the password entered is not shown in plain text - the password you see in plan text is the output of an echo (and the use of awk) just to show what has been entered, and it is only for testing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the instruction on https://github.com/Homebrew/install, you can just set environment variable `NONINTERACTIVE=1`. e.g. do

```
NONINTERACTIVE=1 /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```